# How to use ISNULL Function in mysql version (6.0.11-alpha-community)

Tags: mysql

I written the query without ISNULL Function in mysql

```
   SELECT DISTINCT s.st_symbol,f.symbol,f.closeprice,f.ltp,f.prevclprice AS CLOSE,(((LTP-prevclprice)/(prevclprice*100))) AS per_change,f.expdate
  FROM stmp_stocks_qty AS s
  JOIN tbl_intraday_nsefoprice_latest AS f ON s.st_symbol = f.symbol AND f.ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tbl_intraday_nsefoprice_latest GROUP BY SYMBOL)
  ORDER BY s.st_symbol,f.ExpDate DESC,f.createdon DESC;
```

This query is working fine and while I execute this query I get the null values in my column based on the calculation "(((LTP-prevclprice)/(prevclprice*100)))" .

ex:

[image: per_change having null]

To avoid this null value I used ISNULL Function and written a query like

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s.st_symbol,f.symbol,f.closeprice AS CLOSE,ISNULL(((LTP-prevclprice)/(prevclprice*100)),0) AS per_change,f.expdate
  FROM stmp_stocks_qty AS s
  JOIN tbl_intraday_nsefoprice_latest AS f ON s.st_symbol = f.symbol AND f.ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tbl_intraday_nsefoprice_latest GROUP BY SYMBOL)
  ORDER BY s.st_symbol,f.ExpDate DESC,f.createdon DESC;
```

But while I executing this query I'm getting this king of error

```
Query:  SELECT DISTINCT s.st_symbol,f.symbol,f.closeprice AS CLOSE,isnull(((LTP-prevclprice)/(prevclprice*100)),0) AS per_change,f.expd...

Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
---------------------------------------------------
```

Here my intension is if any column is passing null value into the column it should became a 0.

Suggest me how can I achieve this without error.

I'm new to mysql
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Use `COALESCE` instead of ISNULL, _COALESCE(((LTP-prevclprice)/(prevclprice*100)),0)_

Comment: The error is pointing in you in the right direction. Have you looked at [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) and the correct parameters? And @Nacho suggest a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL equivalent of ISNULL is IFNULL

or

you can use coalesce(), so your query will be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.st_symbol,f.symbol,f.closeprice AS CLOSE, coalesce(((LTP-prevclprice)/(prevclprice*100)),0) AS per_change,f.expd...
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) is a function which accepts only one argument. Function tests does the argument IS NULL and returns TRUE (1) or FALSE (1) depends on the testing result.

The function which accepts 2 arguments and returns first value if it is not NULL and second value otherwise is [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull).